# Chain rule for matrix derivatives

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ denotes the set of $n \times n $ real matrices. I have a closed form expression for
$$
g(A) := \frac{\partial}{\partial A} f(A).
$$

The goal is to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial B} f(C'BC)$ where $B$ and $C$ are $k \times k$ and $k \times n$ matrices, respectively (so that $C'BC$ is a $n \times n $ matrix as it should be). I am thinking it must equal $ C'g(C'BC)C $ but I want to make sure and get some reference for this chain rule. Thanks a lot for your help.

[EDIT] It seems clear that my conjecture is wrong. Any help to get me on the correct path would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning leading to your supposed result?

Comment: If $g(A)$ is $n\times n,$ you cannot multiply $C'$ by $g(C'BC)$ on the left, and the same for $C$ on the right.

Comment: Yeah, I actually came back to confess that it seems my conjecture is wrong. Thanks @enzotib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A:\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as $A(B)=C'BC$

Denote also $g(A)=[g_{ij}(A)],~A=[a_{ij}],~c=[c_{ij}]$

Then
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial B}f(C'BC)=&
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial B}(f\circ A)(B)\\
\triangleq&\left[\dfrac{\partial (f\circ A)}{\partial b_{kl}}(B)\right]\\
=&\left[\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a_{ij}}\left(A(B)\right)\dfrac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial b_{kl}}(B)\right]\\
=&\left[\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^ng_{ij}\left(A(B)\right)\dfrac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial b_{kl}}(B)\right]\\
=&\left[\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^ng_{ij}\left(C'BC\right)c_{ki}c_{lj}\right]\\
=&\left[c_kg(C'BC)c_l'\right]\\
=&Cg(C'BC)C'
\end{align}

where $c_k$ denotes the $k$-th line of $C$

Answer (score 1):

Denote the known gradient as the matrix $G$ and use it to write the *differential* of the function.
$$\eqalign{
G &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial A} \doteq g(A) \\
df &= G:dA \\
}$$
Now use the relationship $\,A=C^TBC\,$ to change the independent variable ( from $A\to B\,$)
$$\eqalign{
df &= G:d(C^TBC) \\
   &= G:C^TdB\,C \\
   &= CGC^T:dB \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}
   &= CGC^T \\\\
}$$
In the above, a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
M:N = {\rm Tr}(M^TN) = {\rm Tr}(N^TM) = N:M \\
}$$